# Specific CSS layout with fixed elements and multiple scrollbars

Tags: html, css, positioning

For the last days I had some issues with a specific layout I want for a website. I have added an image to explain the layout and also some CSS code I have been trying out with below. I tried using floating layout, absolute positioning and all kinds of combinations to fix the layout but I can't seem to get it right. I hope any of you guys could help me out with this.

Here is the layout image:

[image: Image with description how the layout should be]

Here is the CSS code:

```
html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.header {
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
}

.left {
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:30%;
    min-width:300px;
    height:100%;
}

.right {
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    right:0;
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
}


.footer {
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:500px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you wanted? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GyN9P/1/)

REMOVE

```
.wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
}

.left
{
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:30%;
    min-width:300px;
    height:100%;
}

.right
{
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    right:0;
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
}
```

REPLACE WITH

```
div.left, 
div.right {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
    width: 30%;
}

.right {
    width: 70%;
}
```

**UPDATE**  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GyN9P/2/)

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px; /* If the window gets bellow 600px .left will stay 30% of 600 and .right will stay 70% of 600*/
}

div.left, 
div.right {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
}

.left {
    width: 30%;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    width: 70%;
    background:green;
}

.header
{
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

.wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
}



.footer
{
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:500px;
    height:40px;
}​​​
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply. When I add a 'min-width:300px' to the '.left' class in the code you provided and resize the window the '.right' class disappears.

Comment: In order for the layout to be fluid you cannot use a set width in 'px' must be percentage. Do you need the left column to have a min width of '300px' or can you settle for a 'min-width: x%'? 'x' being any percentage smaller than 30%

Comment: The problem is that if the size gets smaller than 300px the layout of the left side must have a horizontal scrollbar to preserve the layout of the list view that is being showed. But if it is not possible than I would like to thank you for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

We eventually used flex-box layout to be able to use for example 300px and let the rest be fluid.